# TextBoxWatermarkExtender losing text after Response.Write

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, watermark, response.write

I am exporting an asp.net `gridview` to an excel sheet by `Response.Write(*stringBuilder*)`, but when the button is clicked `TextBoxes`are losing `TextBoxWatermarkExtender` Text. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I think that after the export button is clicked and processed, the ajax watermarkextender should be recalled by javascript in code behind. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Depending on how your page is laid out, the response.write may be placing code above the doctype definition.  When that happens it can cause issues with javascript execution.  Just a thought.

Comment: are you using an update panel ?

Comment: Yes I am using 2 update panels. One outer one for the whole page and an inner one for the export button which has a trigger:  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lBtnPrint" /> 

The TextBox and its TextBoxWatermarkExtender are in the outer updatepanel.

Comment: Hi... I still need to solve this issue. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your CSS... 
Work Like This..

```
.yourWatermarkedClass

{

color: Black;
font-family: Arial;

font-size: 11px;
border: solid 1px #a9a9a9;

text-indent:2px;
vertical-align:middle;

text-align:right;
background-image:url(../images/yourfileName.png);

background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how your answer is related. The TextBoxWatermarkExtender does work. It stops displaying its text after the print button is clicked.